# different output from tutorial code for basic red Triangle program in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been following openGL tutorial at ogldev.atspace.co.uk.
In the fourth tutorial I ran into some problems. (ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial04/tutorial04.html)

first when I compiled the code I got this error message :GL version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
Error compiling shader type 35633: '0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, and 1.00 ES.

Looking around for this error I found out that I needed to initialize a GL core profile.

so I added these two lines to the code :

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3 );
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

this made my code compile and run but instead of a red triangle in the tutorial I get a red quad in the upper left corner.

here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include "ogldev_util.h"
#include "math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

const char* pVSFileName = "shader.vs";
const char* pFSFileName = "shader.fs";

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void AddShader(GLuint ShaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLuint ShaderObj = glCreateShader(ShaderType);

    if (ShaderObj == 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader type %d\n", ShaderType);
        exit(0);
    }

    const GLchar* p[1];
    p[0] = pShaderText;
    GLint Lengths[1];
    Lengths[0]= strlen(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, p, Lengths);
    glCompileShader(ShaderObj);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(ShaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        GLchar InfoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObj, 1024, NULL, InfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", ShaderType, InfoLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObj);
}

static void CompileShaders()
{
    GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (ShaderProgram == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    string vs, fs;

    if (!ReadFile(pVSFileName, vs)) 
    {
        exit(1);
    };

    if (!ReadFile(pFSFileName, fs)) 
    {
        exit(1);
    };

    AddShader(ShaderProgram, vs.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(ShaderProgram, fs.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Success = 0;
    GLchar ErrorLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Success);

    if (Success == 0) 
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error linking shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &Success);
    if (!Success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3 );
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 04");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("GL version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    CompileShaders();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

their output:[image]

my output[image]

Comment: Why are you Mesa3d? This is a software implementation of OpenGl as far as i know. If your platform is PC, then install latest graphics drivers (AMD/nvidia) to get the "normal" hardware accelerated opengl.  From your error message it looks like you are using or requesting GLSL 3.3 features (possibly by a  `#version 330` in your shaders), and this is not supported by mesa3d yet.

Comment: Also, if that does not make your problem go away, i advice to include using `glGetError` to check for errors on a regular basis, because anything can go terribly wrong on the gpu-side and you won't notice. I don't know why nobody seems to do this anymore in tutorials etc ...

Comment: @ThomasMy mesa doesn't give the error, if I make the core profile but then it screws up the final image. Also the only drivers available for my graphics card on ubuntu are opensource ones and don't they all rely on mesa for their openGL implementation? and where do you want me to insert glGetError? thanks btw

Comment: I see. I'd put a routine that retrieves the error code and prints it somewhere if it is not GL_NO_ERROR at the end of your display func. If an error happens you can start debugging. That you most likely have inserted only a few new lines and do not need to debug everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use [Vertex Array Objects (VAOs)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), which are mandatory in core GL. That this code still displays something instead of generating an error at `glDrawArrays` is already beyond the spec.